# Redis queue: call BLPOP/BRPOP inside a loop?

Tags: node.js, redis, message-queue

I want to build a simple queue system with Redis, without relying on pub/sub. So my (Nodejs) consumer will call `BRPOP` on a list, nothing very original.

The question is whether to fully and exclusively rely on the   blocking behavior of a no-timeout `BRPOP` --meaning it will block the connection indefinitely until an event is pushed to the list-- or call `BRPOP` inside a loop, with a short timeout.

What would be the advantages and drawbacks of both solutions? For example, could a long blocking connection/process be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was keeping two clients open for each worker: one for the blocking function brpoplpush, and the other for making non-blocking redis calls the worker might need.